# In the flag-weight page, the vote block is not rendered correctly when the question/answer has been down voted

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

A flagged question/answer that has been down voted is shown as in the following screenshot.
The minus sign is in the middle of the grey block, and the number is partially shown outside that grey block; it seems the number is also truncated.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be fixed (no idea when, though).

Answer (score 3):

Posting this as an answer because of a screenshot alone.

This is also a problem in the Answer activity page on a user's profile page. Any negative number will cause the content to overflow;

[image: Negative Vote Content Overflow]